# Is there a way in Laravel Nova to allow sorting on a column which is populated by a function call?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to allow a populated column in a Nova Lens to be sortable. The root data that populates my Number field comes from a function called during lens initialization to reach out to an API.

For some reason, I can either populate or sort the column values, but not both. Any idea what I am missing?

This code works (all values are populated) but is not sortable:

```php
Number::make('Months Remaining', function () { 
    return $this->foo('timeRemainingInMonths');
})
    ->sortable()
    ->onlyOnIndex(),
```

This code works (all values are populated) but is not sortable:

```php
Number::make('Months Remaining', function () { 
    return $this->foo('timeRemainingInMonths');
})
    ->sortable(function ($query, $direction) {
        $query->orderBy(
'timeRemainingInMonths', $direction);
    })
    ->onlyOnIndex(),
```

This code throws an warning, saying `Argument 1 passed to sortable is expected to be type bool, string given`, but then still results in all values being populated, but is not sortable:

```php
Number::make('Months Remaining', function () { 
    return $this->foo('timeRemainingInMonths');
}) 
    ->sortable('timeRemainingInMonths')
    ->onlyOnIndex();
```

Result of the above three attempts:

[image: Failure: populated but not sortable]

This code is sortable but populates no values:

```php
Number::make('Months Remaining', 'timeRemainingInMonths')
    ->sortable()
    ->onlyOnIndex(),
```

Result of the above one attempt:
[image: Failure: sortable but not populated]

The `foo` function has been renamed in this post, but here is the content of that function:

```
private function foo($field)
{
    $lotNo = $this->lotNo()->first()->lot_no;
    foreach (self::$bar as $mixtureLot) {
        if ($mixtureLot['lotNo'] == $lotNo) {
            return $mixtureLot[$field];
        }
    }
    return 'N/A';
}
```

The `bar` variable will always be an array populated from an API call. If it has data, each item in the array will be in the form

```php
[
    'lotNo' => <string>,
    'qtyRemaining' => <integer>,
    'binIds' => <array of strings>,
    'manufactureDate' => <string>,
    'expirationDate' => <string>, 
    'timeRemainingInDays' => <integer>,
    'timeRemainingInMonths' => <integer>,
];
```

Comment: I do not have access to the Nova source code, but the documentation says you can only do `->sortable()`, there is no argument at all... Where did you read that you can pass a string or a function to sort?

Comment: Hey there, I must admit it was just Hail Mary guessing and checking in the hopes that a semi-standard PHP parameter would do the trick haha. Usually, if I add the `->sortable()` I'm golden, but not in this case. Something about that function it doesn't like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, reading the documentation again, there is this text for computed fields (when you pass data to the field as a second argument):

> Since they are not associated with a database column, computed fields may not be sortable

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields

Comment: Well dang, not the answer I was looking for but that does check out. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! I am sorry it is not what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom query builder to your model overriding the `Model::newEloquentBuilder()` method and then overriding the `Builder::orderBy()` method of the builder:

```php
public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'asc'): static
{
    if($column === 'your-computed-field')
    {
        // your logic
    }
    else
    {
        parent::orderBy($column, $direction);
    }

    return $this;
}
```